# Having an issue in inner join query not unique alias table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was basically trying to run my queries, I had no trouble with syntax but as soon as I try to run it, I get the following.

```
Select happy.customer_num
From happy
inner Join happy On Happy.Customer_num =
Account.Customer_num Where Account.Account_Num = "";
```

`Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'happy'`

Does any body understand this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, one of those "happy"s should be `account`:

```
Select h.customer_num 
From happy h inner Join
     account a
     On h.Customer_num = a.Customer_num
Where a.Account_Num = '';
```

Also note the use of table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.